# VB given number sorting

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'm trying to sort out specific people who are login into the vb solution.  Basically these people have a login number, lets say `1111111`.  I am trying to say if the 5th digit is a `9`, so `1111911` then give them a message and don't let them proceed any further.

I have one in place now that says IF `givenNumber.StartsWith ("")` then
I would like something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done with [String.Substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position and has a specified length.

Simple example:

```
If strLoginID.Substring(4, 1) = "9" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enjoy this public service announcement concerning unicorns.")
End If
```

You may also want to check if the string has at least 5 characters to avoid run-time exceptions:

```
If strLoginID.Length >=5 Then
    If strLoginID.Substring(4, 1) = "9" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enjoy this public service announcement concerning unicorns.")
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("ID not long enough; you are not worthy to be in the presence of unicorns.")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example suggests that givenNumber is a string. You can treat a `String` as an array of `Char`.

```
If givenNumber(4) = "9"c Then
    '5th digit is "9"
End If
```